# Can we schedule multiple sql queries in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Is that possible to schedule multiple queries in Redshift?

Comment: [Scheduling a query on the Amazon Redshift console - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor-schedule-query.html)

Comment: I went through that previously but the thing can we schedule multiple queries?